# nginx: try_files using wrong directory

Tags: nginx

So I've got these two location blocks on nginx:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
}

location /v1/merchants {
    root /var/www/public/api-merchants;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}
```

`location /` routes to the correct `index.php`, but `location/v1/merchants` is supposed to redirect to `/var/www/public/api-merchants/index.php`, but instead it redirects to the same `index.php` as `location /`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which location do you try to access in your browser?

Comment: Well I'm trying to reach /v1/merchants but it ends up using the same script as /

Comment: Please include your complete nginx configuration in the question.

Answer (score 1):

The final element of the `try_files` statement is a URI. The URI of the script you want is presumably `/v1/merchants/index.php`. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for details.

If the file is located at `/var/www/public/api-merchants/index.php`, you should be using an `alias` directive and not a `root` directive. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) for details.

You do not have a means to execute PHP files within this new root, so your existing `location ~ \.php` location block will take over. You need to use a nested location block and replicate your PHP statement (e.g. `fastcgi_pass`) within it. Also, use the `^~` modifier to prevent the other `location ~ \.php` location block taking over. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

For example:

```
location ^~ /v1/merchants {
    alias /var/www/public/api-merchants;
    if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite ^ /v1/merchants/index.php last; }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        if (!-f $request_filename) { return 404; }

        include        fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
        fastcgi_pass   ...;
    }
}
```

I avoid using `try_files` with `alias` because of [this issue](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/97). Note [this caution](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) on the use of `if`.